# clickHandler or handleClick or onClick or signUp or handleSignUp or signUpHandler?

Tags: javascript, typescript, coding-style, naming-conventions, prettier

What is the industry standard for function naming convention in **javascript**?

I know it's up to me to follow whatever pattern but I would like to know the industry standard and follow one particular pattern.

```js
const handleClick = () => {
  // sign up logic
}
```

**OR**

```js
const clickHandler = () => {
  // sign up logic
}
```

**OR**

```js
const onClick = () => {
  // sign up logic
}
```

**OR**

```js
const signUp = () => {
  // sign up logic
}
```

**OR**

```js
const handleSignUp = () => {
  // sign up logic
}
```

**OR**

```js
const signUpHandler = () => {
  // sign up logic
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I would vote for *signUp*. A function should not be named after how it is used; it should be succinctly named after what it does (if it has side effects) or what it returns (if it is a pure function).

Here is the scheme I use personally when naming identifiers:

- Variable, or function without side effects

  - Truth-value (boolean):
    **Adjective phrase** or "is" prefix, e.g. *newsletterSent*, *isSignedUp*
  - Not truth-value:
    **Noun phrase**, e.g. *sentNewsletters*, *signedUpCustomers*
- Function with side effects:
  **Verb phrase**, e.g. *signUp*, *sendNewsletter*

Answer (score 1):

Here if full guide with examples of naming: [link](https://www.robinwieruch.de/javascript-naming-conventions)